# Djanjo/Python: passed variable not working as expected in function

Tags: python, django, api, youtube

I'm trying to get the following function working in my views.py file. I'm passing in a keyword to search for (`the_Term`), if I do a print statement, I can see that the variable has been passed correctly however, it is not getting passed to the API call (`q=the_Term`). If I hard code my keyword (`q="my keyword"`) the function works properly.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def search_by_keyword(self,the_Term):
    DEVELOPER_KEY = "MY API KEY"
    YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
    YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME,
                    YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                    developerKey= DEVELOPER_KEY)

    search_response = youtube.search().list(q=the_Term,
                                            part="id,snippet",
                                            maxResults=1).execute()
    videos = []
    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            videos.append((search_result["id"]["videoId"]))

    return 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videos[0]
```

Comment: How is this function being called? What is in `the_Term`?

Comment: Post your urls.py or the url for this view

Comment: I'm getting the_Term from my database in a different function and passing to the search function. It looks like the function doesn't like the fact that it's a database field because I've played with hard coding the value in the function and passing it in and it works fine.

Comment: The url doesn't seem to be an issue because it works fine if I hard code the value in the function. Anyway, I'm sending the primary key in the url and using a class based DetailView 

url(r"(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$",views.IndexView.as_view(),name="post_det"),

Answer (score 0):

I think this somewhat depends on what you mean by "it is not getting passed to the API call". Do you mean that it's evaluating to `None`? Or you're not getting something from the API that you expect? Having limited knowledge of the YouTube API you're using or the rest of the codebase, here's some things to try and look at:

- Is the format of `the_Term` correct? For example, is the YouTube API expecting an encoded or unencoded search query? (Note: Tried both encoded and unencoded in the API explorer and it seemed to work)
- Is there a control character somewhere?
- Is `the_Term` not actually a string, but when you print it it's just executing a `__str__` and for some reason the YT API is not?

If you could provide some more specifics about what you mean by "it's not getting passed" that would help.

Comment: Thanks LFP6, 

When I do a print on print the_Term from inside function, it returns the keyword that I passed in. But, the actual code that makes the API call:

search_response = youtube.search().list(q=the_Term,
                                            part="id,snippet",
                                            maxResults=1).execute()

Doesn't work. 

If I do everything else the same but change q=the_Term to q="some keyword", it goes through and fetches a video like it is supposed to.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error? Does it return nothing?

Comment: Nothing gets returned. I can tell by looking at the Google developer console that a request is being sent to Youtube but I don't get any results. As I said above, if I hard code the keyword and pass it to the API call, it does work. It only doesn't work if I try to use my variable.

Comment: I've been playing with this some more. I'm getting the keyword from my database. That seems to be the issue. The field it is coming from is a charfield. My guess is, this isn't being seen as a string. I tried casting it as a string and it's still not working.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Have you tried storing a simple value (ie one word, no special character) in the database to try your function with? And you are using a function to access the data on a charfield that will return a single value, right (ie `.get()`)?

Comment: Here's the function that gets the term from the db:

[code] def get_search_term(self):
        obj = super(IndexView, self).get_object()
        output =  obj.prod_name [code]

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include the return statement in the above function. The last line is: 

return output